# CKEditor 4 changes html div tag to p tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I would like to know how to display the html as such using CKEditor 4 reactjs.
It displays the editor but the inline style are removed and all div tag changed to P tag.

How to dsiplay the html as it is without changing div to P tag

```
import React from "react";
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react';


class Editor extends React.PureComponent{

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      config: {
        extraAllowedContent: 'div(*)',
        allowedContent: true
      }
     emailbody: `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </head>
        <body  style="background-color: #DAD5CE; font-family:'browntt-regular', Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif">
         <div class="content-box" style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin:25px 0">
                    <div style="height:100%; text-align: center;display:block; ">
                        <div style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 24pt; color: #000">order confirmation</div>
                        <div class="orderdate" style="font-size: 12pt; color: #51545D">order date:
                             <span style="color: #B39137;">${orderdate!''} </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </body>
        </html>`
    }

handleChange = value => {
 this.setState({ emailbody: value });
}
    render(){
       <div>
         <CKEditor
              data={this.state.emailbody}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              config={this.config}
          />
          </div>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue please use 'react-ckeditor-component' rather than the 'ckeditor4-react' like this:

```
import CKEditor from 'react-ckeditor-component';

class Editor extends React.PureComponent{

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     emailbody: `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </head>
        <body  style="background-color: #DAD5CE; font-family:'browntt-regular', Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif">
         <div class="content-box" style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin:25px 0">
                    <div style="height:100%; text-align: center;display:block; ">
                        <div style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 24pt; color: #000">order confirmation</div>
                        <div class="orderdate" style="font-size: 12pt; color: #51545D">order date:
                             <span style="color: #B39137;">${orderdate!''} </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </body>
        </html>`
    }

handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    emailbody: event.target.value
  });
};
    render(){
       <div>
         <CKEditor
              content={this.state.content}
              config={{
                 extraAllowedContent: 'div(*)',
                 allowedContent: true
              }}
               events={{
                  change: this.handleChange
              }}
          />
          </div>
    }

}
```

After wasting too many time, I got this solution of the above question please appreciate it